# Cut-through behaviour for the INET WirelessHost

Tags: omnet++, forwarding, inet

The INET WirelessHost inherits from the StandardHost which has store-and-forward as its default forwarding behaviour. Is there a way to change that behaviour to cut-through? I did not find any fitting parameters in both the StandardHost and WirelessHost modules.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: No, that is not possible and makes no sense.

1. cut-through is a layer 2 (link layer) device feature i.e. switches can support it. It is impossible to do this on layer 3 (network layer) as IP packets can be fragmented, defragmented and the IP header itself can change during routing. So at most, the question should be: can a wireless access point support cut-through? BUT:
2. cut-through implies that the interface can receive and send simultaneously. That's an almost impossible feat for a wireless transciever over a radio medium. (unless the transmission is highly directional (like. StarLink laser links, but in that case they could be considered as wired channels)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! The network i am working with is actually a Starlink satellitenetwork that uses laser links as connections and sends messages over a radio medium.  Sending messages that traverse a high number of satellites results in higher latencys then expected and i thought it could be because of the store-and-forward behaviour. Could the wireless access point of a satellite be changed so that it supports cut-through?

Comment: There are two things here that are washed together: 
- communication between satellites and user equipment over a shared radio medium
- direct inter-satellite point to point communication (only a few satellite supports this AFAIK)

If you want to model starlink properly, you  have to write your own wireless model emulating the behavior of the user terminals, plus you have to model the inter-sat communication with point-to-point links (i.e. you will use wired models there even if the transmission is a laser). Wired transmission models CAN support cut through. (see samples/routing)